# Bookshelf / Knex saving collection too slow

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am calling some data from Google Api and after that I am saving it as a collection into a MySql database using Bookshelf. Here is the method doing that:

```
function getKeywords (start) {
        searchConsole.getKsetGroup(start, page, clientId).then(function(data) {
            var ksetsToSave = Kset.collections.forge(data.rows);
            //...here is the collection being saved tooking more
            //... than 30 seconds to finish
            ksetsToSave.invokeThen('save', null).then(function() {
                if (data.rows.length === 5000) {
                    counter ++;
                    getKeywords(5000*counter);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I've logged every step in the function, and I am sure this is the problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "any thought":

Run your code with `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable set and you will see how long each operation done by `knex` is taking.